# Send JSON Stream Read XML Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, webforms

I have a unique request for me, where I need to send a JSON POST request but read a XML GET.  I have tried this below, but I get an error of

> You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

What do I alter in order for my XML GET to succesful be able to read the response?

```
public bool PerformPost(Dictionary<string, string> dictFormValues, string strPageTitle, string strPageURL, ref string strMessage)
{
    string strEndpointURL = string.Format("websitegoeshere");
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strPostData = "";
    foreach (var d in dictFormValues) { strPostData += d.Key + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(d.Value) + "&"; }
    strPostData += "hs_context=";
    HttpWebRequest r = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strEndpointURL);
    r.Method = "POST";
    r.Accept = "application/json";
    r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    r.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
    r.KeepAlive = false;
    Stream datastream = r.GetRequestStream();
    WebResponse response = r.GetResponse();
    datastream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
    string responsefromserver = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(responsefromserver);
    if (xml.Elements("sid").FirstOrDefault().Value == "1") { return true; }
    else
    {
        var errors = xml.Elements("fail");
        foreach (var error in errors.Elements("fail"))
        {
            strMessage = error.Value;
            return false;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    datastream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't written the post data to the request stream. You will need to call datastream.Write before you call GetResponse.

For example:

```
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPostData);
r.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
datastream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
datastream.Close();
```